# List.Find in Unity environment seems to depend on type casting

Tags: c#, list, casting, unity-game-engine, find

The setup for my List and the item class are as such:

```
public class mapVertex {

  public Vector2 vertex;
  public float x {
    get{ return vertex.x; }
  }
  public float z {
    get{ return vertex.y; }
  }

  public mapVertex(float x, float y) {
    myID = ID++;
    vertex.x = x;
    vertex.y = y;
  }

}

void Start() {
...
    vertexList = new List<mapVertex>();
    for (...)
        vertexList.Add( new mapVertex( (float) 10.1, (float) 11.2 ) );
```

Following immediately in the code is the Find statement. After execution of the below however newEdge.B is equal to null.

```
    for (...)
        mapEdge newEdge = new mapEdge();
        double[] vve = new double[2];
        vve[0] = 10.1;
        vve[1] = 11.2;
        newEdge.B = vertexList.Find(  x => (x.x == (float) vve[0]) && (x.z == (float) vve[1]) );
...
}
```

The below evaluates to true in the expression evaluator in MonoDevelop when I breakpoint on the line in question and the debugger confirms the values look correct, so I'm not sure why List.Find() isn't returning the first element of vertexList.

```
(vertexList[0].x == (float) vve[0]) && (vertexList[0].z == (float) vve[1])
```

Is this possibly related to a type conversion issue? The values of the items in vertexList were originally created by casting double to float (see above), but from what I understand doubles should be deterministic when casting to float.

Edit:

When changing

```
double[] vve = new double[2];
vve[0] = 10.1;
vve[1] = 11.2;
```

to

```
float[] vve = new float[2];
vve[0] = 10.1f;
vve[1] = 11.2f;
```

this seems to work..
Anyone know why?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your approach/code. it should work. Created similar [code here ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HJYqZB) have a look it may help.

Comment: Hmm. Updated that link with a more specific example but the example that works on fiddle does not seem to work when I'm running it inside my Unity project.

Comment: For anyone with a similar issue I worked around this by doing the double to float casting in a separate line into a temporary float[] and then comparing to the value in the temporary array in the predicate instead of directly from the double to float casting. Very strange..